# Question about a statement concerning normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm asking the following: it is true that if $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $K\leq H\leq G$ then $K$ is normal in $H$? I tried to prove it but I failed to do so, so I'm starting to suspect that it is not true. Can you provide me a proof or a counterexample of this statement or hint about its proof?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You know that

$$\;K\lhd G\implies g^{-1}kg\in K\;,\;\;\text{for all elements}\;\;k\in K\,,\,\,g\in G\;$$

Now, $\;H\subset G\; $, so...

Answer (score 1):

It is trivially true because $K\trianglelefteq G$ is equivalent to $gKg^{-1}=K\,,\forall g\in G$.  This condition is met $\forall g\in H$, as $H\subset G$.  Note we do not need normality of $H$.

Comment: Oh, now I get it! Since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $gkg^(-1)$ belongs to $K$ for all $g$ in $G$ it also holds for all $h$ in $H$.